# How to load some information on click event in google timeline chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, google-visualization

I am using [Google Timeline chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline) and want to load some details of City by clicking on the city name but not getting idea how to do that.

[image]

```
<div id="cityData">

   <!-- city information display hear after ajax success -->

</div>

<div id="timeline" style="height: 180px;"></div>
```

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  dataTable.addRows([
    [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
    [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
    [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);

  chart.draw(dataTable);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/whaqcfnx/

Thanks

Comment: Ohh. Sorry for that. I am updating my link. :)

Comment: There's no data on city, only presidents

Comment: @zer00ne I want to load some HTML on click of `Washington, Adams, Jefferson` names but not getting idea.

Comment: @Mr.Happy Please be a little more specific, like where this HTML is coming from, where do you want it, and the code of what you tried so far. If you have no idea what, and where...we can't tell you how.

Comment: I have stored some city's details in my database and want to execute jQuery ajax and want to show response data in HTML but outside of timeline HTML and also I have to pass city name on click event to fetch city information for ajax. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

you can add an event listener to the `text` labels generated by the chart

the `text` elements have an attribute for `'text-anchor'`

the attribute will have a value of `'end'` for the row labels

just need to wait for the `'ready'` event to fire

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['timeline'],
  callback: function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
      [ 'Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
      [ 'Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4) ],
      [ 'Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4) ]]);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      var rowLabels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(rowLabels, function (label) {
        if (label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'end') {
          label.addEventListener('click', displayDetails, false);
        }
      });
    });

    function displayDetails(sender) {
      document.getElementById('cityData').innerHTML = 'City Data for: ' + sender.target.innerHTML;
    }

    chart.draw(dataTable);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline"></div>
<div id="cityData"></div>
```